# compute $P(X\le 2 \textrm{ or } 3<X<8)$ For exponentially distributed x

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-function, self-learning

Suppose X is exponentially distributed with $\lambda=2$.

I want to compute $P(X\le 2 \textrm{ or } 3<X<8)$.

The probability density function of $x$ is $f(x)=2e^{-2x}$.

Then I will find its distribution function as $F(x)=1-e^{-2x}$.

I don’t know exactly, but I think that $P(X\le 2 \textrm{ or } 3<X<8)$ can be calculated as follows:

$$P(X\le 2 \textrm{ or } 3<X<8) = P(X\le 2)+ P(3<X<8)-P(X\le 2, 3<X<8)$$

$$P(X\le 2)=F(2)= 1-e^{-4}$$

$$P(3<X<8)=F(8)-F(3)= e^{-16}-e^{-6}$$

But what is $P(X\le 2, 3<X<8)$?

Or what is the correct way to solve this question?

Comment: Why you think $P(X\le 2, 3<X<8) \ne 0$?

Comment: I don’t know. I have no idea at this point @zkutch

Comment: Can $X$ be less than 2 and greater than 3 simultaneously?

Comment: The given probability is $$\underbrace{P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)}_{=P(X\le 2)}+\underbrace{P(X=4)+P(X=5)+P(X=6)+P(X=7)}_{P(3<X<8)}\ .$$And for each term we have a formula. Or work as in the OP.

Comment: In fact if you check the signs $P(3<X<8)=F(8)-F(3)= e^{-6}-e^{-16}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  Note that the events $\{X \le 2\}$ and $\{3 < X < 8 \}$ are mutually exclusive.

$$P(X \le 2 \text{ or } 3 < X < 8) \\
= P(\{X \le 2\} \cup \{3 < X < 8\})
\\ = P(X \le 2) + P(3 < X < 8) \\= (1 - e^{-4}) + (e^{-6} - e^{-16})
\\ = 1 - e^{-4} + e^{-6} - e^{-16}$$

Note that you've inverted the sign when calculating $P(3 < X < 8)$.

Answer (score 1):

As $X$ is random variable i.e. in particular usual function, then $\{\omega\colon X(\omega)\leqslant 2\} \cap \{\omega\colon 3<X(\omega)< 8\}=\emptyset$, so $P(X\le 2, 3<X<8) = 0$.

Comment: That’s, you mean that $P(X\le 2, 3<X<8)=0$. Isn’t it?

Comment: Yes. Added to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

$X<2$ is an event.  So too is $3 <X <8$.  Since the intervals do not overlap, they are mutually exclusive.

So $P(X <2 \text{ or }3 <X<8) = P(X<2)+P(3<X<8)$ which is $P(X<2) +P(X<8)-P(X\le 3)$.  Since the exponential distribution is continuous, this is also equal to   $P(X\le 2) +P(X\le 8)-P(X\le 3)$ and you can calculate each of these terms from the cumulative distribution function and gives $1-e^{-
4}+e^{-6}-e^{-16}$

Meanwhile $P(X <2,3 <X<8)$ is read as  $P(X <2 \text{ and  }3 <X<8)$ and since the events are mutually exclusive, this is $0$